# Как отследить какие dll загружает EXE Сторонним софтом

Tags: dll, mingw, g++

Вопрос скорее не по программированию а по инструментам доведения до ума и публикации готовой програми.

Есть готовая программа которая написана на С++ CodeBlocks g++ mingw, собрана все в работает как надо.

Переношу на другой комп, запустил, скопировал все dll ки что попросила программа, но в результате выдает ошибку (0x00007b) ошибка внешней библиотеки, еще раз запустел на компе для разработки уже с скопированными библиотеками, всё работает.

Так как предполагаю что dll грузиться в начале с паки программы а после из системи, значит системная библиотека в тестовом компе не подходит программе, нужно скопировать в готовый продукт, но как узнать какую.

**Посоветуйте программку какая поможет отследить какие ресурсы подгружает программа.**

Предыдущая версия этой же программы но без витореного сервера и использования потоков работает на тестовом пк.

Теперь начал понимать Java разработчиков :) Плевать на скорость зато зависимостями занимается ява машина. Толку с быстрой программы которая не работает.

Comment: Нет, это вопрос как раз по программированию. Дело в том, что определить и документировать зависимости, которые потребуются для запуска программы, реализующей определенные функционал, необходимо еще ДО написания этого функционала. Ну а если уж вы забили на управление зависимостями, то никого, кроме себя, вам винить не стоит. А как разработчик Java, также скажу, что ява машина зависимостями занимается не в большей мере, чем динамический линкер. Ну а посмотреть, какие dll загружены в процесс, можно например в Process Explorer.

Comment: Если используете самостоятельный mingw-w64 (со сборкой из msys2 все несколько сложнее), то проще всего просто пойти в каталог `bin`, где лежит компилятор (файлы `gcc`, `g++` и т.д.) и оттуда скопировать все библиотеки к своей программе. Там этих библиотек примерно 8 штук. А потом можно по одной удалять (копии конечно, которые уже лежат возле Вашей программы) и определить необходимый минимум (да, чтобы проверить запускаемость достаточно запустить сеанс консольки без путей к mingw). А еще, можно статически собирать свою программу и тогда не надо будет заботиться о библиотеках.

Comment: Благодарю, скопировал все, у меня их всего 440 штук, и заработало, сейчас буду чистить в первую очередь от тех библиотек которые не использовал в проекте так как 400 мб дллок больше чем программа с данными вист. А статическую компиляцию еще не использовал в Codeblocs не знаю как, потом попробую поискать как компилировать , н боюсь что библиотека bass может не застопорить весь проект при статической компиляции.